# OpenCL floating point precision management

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpuimage

I am trying to parallelize an object localization algorithm on a GPU during my internship. But the OpenCL maximum floating point precision became quite problematic.

The reference algorithm is implemented using double precision all the time especially for the SVM classifier and descriptors. Mine is implemented in single precision causing errors. I checked my normalized errors and I got what I expected at several points of my program (10^-6).

However these errors become much more importants after the classification step of the process.

**Is there any way to simulate double precision values with a GPU supporting only single precision ?**

PS : I can use double precision on my GPU (Nvidia GTS450) but the program will be tested on several platforms with much less power which probably means no double precision.

Comment: http://andrewthall.org/papers/df64_qf128.pdf

Comment: Thanks I will study it !

Answer (score 0):

This might be of interest to you: http://www.bealto.com/mp-mandelbrot_fp128-opencl.html